# How to design the mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb, collections

The scenario for my collection is: 
User A can block other users and other users can block user A, i.e many to many relation.
But my question is how to design the User class.

Just put all blocked user in some kind of list or embedding a Block class to the User class.

A possible solution:

```
public class User
{

 String id;
  String username;
String password;
String email;
List<User> blockedUserEmails;
//getter and setters
}
```

Or

```
public class User
{

String id;
 String username;
String password;
String email;
//getter and setters

 List<String> blockedUserEmailsInAList;
 }
```

Or

```
  public class User
  {

String id;
String username;
String password;
 String email;

@Embedded
List<Blockee> blockedUserId;

//getter and setters
}
```

Which one of the classes is best for the propose?

Grateful for any help.

Update

User A doesn't like that User B,C and so on will be in the same group and can block them from the group.
And maybe User B neither wants that User a is the same group so they can block each other. When I show the list of possible Users and groups so they are invisible fore each other and for example User A can't choose User B or vice verse.

Comment: "Best" by what standard?

Comment: I just need some solution which is working well with ,at most, 500 users.
(Using Spring MVC)

Comment: "working well" by what standard? Please tell us what would be a good or a bad solution *for you*.

Comment: What will you need to use the blocked user list for? Will you only need the list of email addresses of people the user has blocked?

Comment: Please check the updates. And I don't understand what you mean by standard. Please can you explain that for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A User should have a List of IDs of the user which he blocked, so you can identify the blocked users with a minimum of provided information and you don't have to worry about redundant information getting inconsisted.

Embedding the whole User will lead to a recursive explosion, because the embedded blocked user can also have embedded users, and so on.

```
public class User {
  String id;
  String username;
  String password;
  String email;
  List<String> blockedUserIds;
  //getter and setters
}
```